# Rename tag [google-drive-team-drive] to [google-drive-shared-drive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It's difficult keeping up with Google product renames and product cancellations but Google Team Drives are now Google Shared Drives. I recently proposed some changes to the [tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-drive-team-drive/info) that were accepted but the tag name itself still has the old product name in it.

I think it would make sense to rename the tag to reflect the current product name.

On the other hand, only ~203 questions have been tagged with it, most of which have very few upvotes and about half of which have no accepted answer. If there's a process for removing a tag (and just letting people tag questions with the more general [google-drive] tag) that would be another way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

## [google-drive-shared-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-shared-drive) ← [google-drive-team-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-team-drive)

I've merged the tags and created the synonym mapping shown above.

There are currently 203 questions tagged [google-drive-shared-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-shared-drive). I lack the subject-matter expertise to make the call whether this is a useful tag on its own, or whether it should be merged into [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive). If you want to discuss that, please post a new question focused around that so that we can get buy-in from people with expertise in the technology.

Note that the number of upvotes and/or accepted answers has no relevance on whether a tag should continue to exist. We care only about whether that tag is a useful way to categorize questions, and specifically to help experts and/or answer-seekers find the relevant questions.

If there is something "special" or "unique" about a Shared Drive, compared to the standard Google Drive, then having this special tag is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Cody. Shared Drives do behave quite differently, particularly when it comes to API access which is obviously of relevance to StackOverflow, so your recommendation to keep the tag makes sense.
Thanks for making the change and adding the synonym mapping!